# SQL Tracing in VS2010 load test showing unrelated results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I'm trying to do some SQL tracing on a Visual Studio 2010 load test. It's working, but I'm getting back some unrelated SQL traffic from other users and automated processes.

I verified that it's unrelated by creating a test that pulls down google.com repeatedly. Even this test still shows SQL traffic from our system.

Because of this, it's hard to tell what SQL traffic is worth looking at, and what's just background noise.

Is there a way I can configure SQL tracing to show only traffic related to my load test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, as far as I know there is no appropriate way for us to filter the databases to trace in the SQL Tracing Connect String. Just remember that the system under test (web/app+db) should be dedicated to the test.

In my company, we simply start a separate trace with SQL Server Profiler with specific filters (applicationname or login)

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way, but if we can't, we can't. Thanks!